# Terminal shows "?

Tags: terminal, bash

I was editing .bash_profile and after I saved it ,terminal shows nothing.How can I reset it to previous mode.This is how it looks now.[image]

I changed the value of PS1 variable.I don't have any knowledge about terminal.Please help.

Comment: What does your `PS1` look like? Note it is just the prompt that changed, you can work "normally".

Comment: I am not able to open .bash_profile now.

Comment: What did you do? What if you open another tab? Why aren't you able to open this file: permissions / cannot write?

Comment: Terminal shows "Trace/BPT trap: 5".If i try to "open -a TextEdit.app .bash_profile".

Comment: What if you `vi .bash_profile`?

Answer (score 1):

The `PS1` environment variable defines what the bash prompt looks like. The default varies among distros, but is generally something like this:

```
PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
```

The [bash manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) has an explanation of `PS1` values under the heading "Prompting".

---

You can apply PS1 values to your current terminal session by pressing *Control+C* several times, then pasting in the line of code above and pressing *return* or *enter*. That should get your environment behaving normally long enough to edit your bash profile unless something else is wrong.

If something else is wrong with your profile, and bash is completely broken, you can temporarily use a different shell (one that doesn't care about your bash_profile) with the "New Command..." option in Terminal.app's file menu. When prompted for a command, enter `/bin/zsh`. You should then get a usable terminal window which you can use to edit or move your .bash_profile.

Comment: @roshan: Can you open it through something else (GUI)?

Comment: Thanks for the help.I was able to open .bash_profile using "nano .bash_profile".For those who find similar problem this http://natelandau.com/my-mac-osx-bash_profile/ will be helpful.